# Thunderbird w/ Webmail

Tags: email, thunderbird, webmail

Is there anything that's basically a webUI for thunderbird?

I've been keeping my mail in thunderbird for years now, but I'd rather be able to pull mail from ISPs/Gmail/etc. and combine them in a single place.  I want to have some kind of webmail frontend that can access the Thunderbird database to show me my mail.

Comment: I'm confused... what are you trying to do here? Do you want to use Thunderbird with your webmail accounts? For purely "webmail" accounts, that isn't possible, but most ISP's and Gmail allow SMTP and/or IMAP access to their email accounts which is something Thunderbird can do.

Comment: @acejavelin, no, basically the opposite of that.  I currently have thunderbird working to download mail from my ISPs.  I want to have some kind of webmail frontend that can access the thunderbird database to show me my mail.  Does that make more sense?

Answer (score 0):

You can come sorta close to what you describe, but not exactly.  You can't access the Thunderbird database from a webmail service because it doesn't work in that direction.  So if you download your messages with POP3, delete them from the provider server, and then do stuff to them in Thunderbird, the result isn't accessible from a web service.

You would need to keep your messages at each provider's server and do the work there through Thunderbird and a webmail service as "front-ends" using IMAP.  Thunderbird can do that, and some webmail providers can also.  I'm pretty sure Gmail is one that can act as an email client for other providers' emails.

So you would set up say Gmail similar to how you set up Thunderbird, using IMAP to interface with the other provider accounts.  You would then have the equivalent of a single access point, usable from both Thunderbird and, in this example, Gmail.

Note that this applies only to new messages and old ones still on the providers' servers.  If you wanted to include old messages that are now only in Thunderbird, you would need to look at export options (native or third party), which would depend on the webmail client.  You may be able to export the historical messages and import them into the webmail client so they would also be accessible from there.  If a compatible export option isn't available, you could do something like resend the old messages to yourself.  Note, though, that this will create duplicate messages that would need to be managed in two locations.

Comment: So, If I understand what you're saying correctly, I'm thoroughly in the territory of "you need to write your own", then?

Comment: @StackTracer, if your requirement is to access and use the Thunderbird database from a web app, I'm not aware of anything that does that.  My answer was that you can accomplish essentially the same result easily with existing tools, just a different mechanism.

Comment: @StackTracer, another thought.  There are now some Thunderbird add-ons that are supposed to do a good job of syncing Thunderbird with cloud-based email servers.  The main focus is Outlook (if you use Outlook Online as your webmail client), but they may also work with gMail or Yahoo, perhaps others.  I haven't had a need for this, so you would have to explore.  But the concept would be that the Thunderbird add-on would keep Thunderbird and your webmail client synced.  Then you could access the same content through the webmail client.